# Error inserting values from csv file to vector in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, csv

```
QVector <QString> frequency;
QVector <QString> gain;
QString ref_data;
QStringList rowOfData;
QStringList rowData;

if (ReferenceData.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    ref_data = ReferenceData.readAll();
    rowOfData = ref_data.split("\n");
    ReferenceData.close();
}

for (int x = 9; x < rowOfData.size(); x++) {
    rowData = rowOfData.at(x).split(",");
    frequency.push_back(rowData[0]);
    gain.push_back(rowData[1]);
}
```

I read all the data from a file. When I use `push_back`, I get an error `QList<T>::operator[] "index out of range"`. I also used `frequency.push_back(rowData.at(0));`, then I get `QList<T>::at "index out of range"` error!

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: What are rowData, frequency and gain?

Comment: Did you run your code in a debugger? Did you check the value of `rowOfData.at(x)`? Did you check that `rowData` really contains at least two values?

Comment: Yes I did that. I actually printed all those values onto a Text area using `textEdit->append(rowData[0])` or `textEdit->append(rowData.at(0))`. They print correct values!

Comment: Did you print those tests right before trying to push the values to frequency and gain? It might be a scope issue depending on what the rest of the code looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Latter loop should handle bad lines, for example like this, just skipping them with debug print:

```
for (int x = 9; x < rowOfData.size(); x++) {
    rowData = rowOfData.at(x).split(",");
    if (rowData.size() >= 2) {
        frequency.push_back(rowData[0]);
        gain.push_back(rowData[1]);
    }
    else qDebug() << "Skipping bad row" << x << rowOfData.at(x);
}
```